# How to fill the void/empty space between two polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge

I am using QGIS 3.01

I am wondering how I can get get rid of the empty space that is splitting the polygon in the picture into two pieces. I know I can edit the polygons together, but is there a better tool for doing this? Like some kind of buffer tool that merge the two polygon?

[image: Two polygons]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GRASS 7.4 and his function v.clean. You can find some examples on this page
https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.clean.html.